# Problemas em um array de strings de uma estrutura

Tags: c, array, arquivo

Estou a ter um problema sobre um array de strings que estou a tentar aceder apartir de uma estrutura. A estrutura  está colocada num `header.h` que tem o seguinte formato :

```
typedef struct {

 char *produtos[200000];
 int contador;
} Produtos,*ProdutosP;
```

No meu `main.c` , fiz uma função que coloca no array de strings `char *produtos[200000];` o counteúdo de um ficheiro linha a linha.
Eis a função :

```
int lerProdutos (FILE *fd )   {

char buff [64];
p->contador = 0;
if (fd == NULL)
    return 1;

  while (fgets (buff,64,fd) != NULL )
  { 
    p->produtos[p->contador] = aplica (buff);         
    p->contador++;
  } 
  return p->contador;
}
```

Quando tento a aceder á posição 1 , 2 , 3 .. o array apenas amostra a ultima linha do ficheiro de onde estou a copiar linha a linha para o array.
Quando invoco o array noutra função o conteúdo que está presente no array é lixo , o que me deixa a ideia que o array não é global.

Como devo fazer para que o array receba o que é suposto e que dê para aceder-lo de uma forma global?

**PS:** O ficheiro que estou a aceder linha a linha para colocar no array tem o seguinte formato :

```
AF1184
AF1198
FD1083
DV1293
DV1294
...
```

a função `aplica` está assim definida :

```
char *aplica (char *str) {

  char *tokenPtr;
  tokenPtr = strtok(str, "\n \t");

   return tokenPtr;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando usas

```
char *produtos[200000];
```

tens um array de (200000) apontadores.

Com o teu código todos esses apontadores apontam para o resultado da função `aplica()`.
O que precisas de fazer é atribuir um valor diferente a cada apontador (possivelmente precedido de `malloc()` e `strcpy()`).

Comment: Sim! É isso! Tava a procurar a razão de estar a falhar e agr @pmg já funciona. Obrigado
PS: Este array funciona globalmente ?